# How to map() on nested array in a clear way

Tags: javascript

Newbie here. Please review the following piece of code and suggest how would you write it in a more clear way, because as a newbie, all my ways are way more procedural etc.

```
  arr.map((p) =>
    p.id === pId
      ? p.bList.map((b) =>
          b.id === bId
            ? b.fList.map((f) =>
                f.id === fId ? console.log('magic happens here') : f
              )
            : b
        )
      : p
  );
```

I didn't put real names in purpose, so you could see how unreadable it is and very confusing to understand what is going on.

Update:
I'm trying to run an operation(get data/modify/delete etc) on a nested array. I'm using Immer, so I actually don't need to take care of mutating the original data, so there's no specific reason to use `map()` for example.

Update2:
Here is an example of the array I have:

```
    const arr = [
        {
          id: 123,
          // data,
          bList: [
            {
              id: 24,
              // data,
              fList: [
                {
                  id: 51,
                  // data,
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
```

So at the above example, I try to modify the `fList` object that match `id` 51

Comment: `I didn't put real names in purpose, so you could see how unreadable it is and very confusing to understand what is going on` so you made it more confusing on purpose? What are you trying to achieve? This is not a valid question.

Comment: This is very unreadable code... please try to strike a balance between code readibility and conciseness

Comment: what's your code trying to do?

Comment: Maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place, because https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199680/whats-acceptable-practice-for-stack-overflow-code-review-for-several-source-fil

Comment: Thanks, I tried to modify my question, did an update on it, does this makes more sense now?

Comment: May I ask you what you want to achieve, with that code? I suspect one of the reasons why it is hard to read is because you might be using the wrong approach to the problem; maybe `map()` is not what you really need and some other array method would be a better fit for your use case (maybe `find()`?)

Comment: Doesn't really make sense yet. This is basically obfuscated code, it means nothing to us. Please provide readable and meaningful example, explain your data structure and your intentions so we can help.

Comment: I did another Update with an example of array, obviously I don't have any real example as I'm learning all of this

Comment: I think it is very peculiar you know all the ID's, `pId` `bId` and `fId`. That makes this an awkward question to answer, as this isn't a very common scenario. What are you trying to learn? Maybe we can point you in a direction. For example, recursion, functional programming or algorithms are three keywords you might google to help you understand the ways to solve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should chain it with a pipeline. For example like this:

```
  arr
 .filter(p => p.id === pId)
 .flatMap(p => p.bList)
 .filter(b => b.id === bId)
 .forEach(elm => console.log(elm))
```

Comment: It doesn't lose any data, that data is still in the original array, but it does not map the data back to the original array if that is what you try to achieve.

Comment: Wow, yes... this works indeed! I modified it with the fList, so it would work on my example, this is so much clear now, thanks. Are there build in functions like `filter` and `flatMap`, but ones that modify the same array you're working on and don't return a complete new array each time?

Comment: @joputy yes, that's true, that's why you chain it. For example FlatMat returns a new array and on that array you apply filter and on the array that returns filter you apply the forEachLoop. You could store it in a new array or if you want to modify the original array you could assign it to this variable and do the forEach loop with this array.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to modify an object deeply nested in your array.
In this case, you can chain a series of `Array.prototype.find()` using optional chaining (`?.`) and do something like:

```js
const itemToUpdate = arr.find(p => p.id === pId)?.
    bList.find(b => b.id === bId)?.
    fList.find(f => f.id === fId)

if (itemToUpdate) {
    console.log('magic happens here')
}
```

Demo:

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 'foo',
    bList: [{
      id: 'bar',
      fList: [{
          id: 'baz',
          key: 'value'
        },
        {
          id: 'baz2',
          key: 'value'
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 'goo',
    bList: [{
      id: 'car',
      fList: [{
          id: 'caz',
          key: 'value'
        },
        {
          id: 'caz2',
          key: 'value'
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
]

const pId = 'foo';
const bId = 'bar';
const fId = 'baz';

const itemToUpdate = arr.find(p => p.id === pId)?.
  bList.find(b => b.id === bId)?.
  fList.find(f => f.id === fId);

if (itemToUpdate) {
  itemToUpdate.key = 'new value'
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is great, thank you, but the problem I see with it, is that it doesn't allow you to modify the same object you're in... so to say the one that meet the criteria of `f.id === fId`. So I would need to run inside of it another optional chaining in order for it to work, and that is kinda messy... maybe there a better approach that I'm not aware of

Comment: Objects are passed by reference, therefore when you modify `itemToUpdate` you are modifying exactly the same `f` object you found, not a copy. In fact, when you `console.log(arr)` you see the updated `'new value'` into the original array.

Comment: A quick demo of the concept is available here: https://jsfiddle.net/pkLmhes6/